# React Native - tipsi-stripe package generating errors on build (unable to resolve dependencies)

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie to RN, currently working on a React Native 0.55.4 app, which had been working perfectly fine. Now I need to accept payments so I installed the tipsi-stripe package and configured it as in the docs. When I build (Android), I get the following error:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.8.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wallet/11.8.0/play-services-wallet-11.8.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wallet/11.8.0/play-services-wallet-11.8.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wallet/11.8.0/play-services-wallet-11.8.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wallet/11.8.0/play-services-wallet-11.8.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wallet/11.8.0/play-services-wallet-11.8.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wallet/11.8.0/play-services-wallet-11.8.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.8.0/firebase-core-11.8.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.8.0/firebase-core-11.8.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.8.0/firebase-core-11.8.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.8.0/firebase-core-11.8.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.8.0/firebase-core-11.8.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/11.8.0/firebase-core-11.8.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:design:27.0.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/design/27.0.0/design-27.0.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0.
  >        Searched in the following locations:
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.pom
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >            file:/Users/drc83/Sites/MyApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.0/support-annotations-27.0.0.jar
  >        Required by:
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.github.tipsi:CreditCardEntry:1.4.8.10 > com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.github.tipsi:CreditCardEntry:1.4.8.10 > com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.github.tipsi:CreditCardEntry:1.4.8.10 > com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
  >            MyApp:app:unspecified > MyApp:tipsi-stripe:unspecified > com.github.tipsi:CreditCardEntry:1.4.8.10 > com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1

Thanks in advance to helping me resolve this. Should you require any further info. please do let me know.